# How to set up my iphone application with twitter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, integration

How to Set up my application with twitter and then register the application with twitter so that people can send tweets from my app.

Please, can anybody help me in resolving this problem.

Answer (score 3):

OAuth is a pain in the butt. Thankfully, [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) combines both [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) by Matt Gemmel and OAuthConsumer (which makes MGTwitterEngine connect to Twitter using OAuth — basic authentification will eventually be taken down by Twitter). The package features a pretty simple example, too.

Don't forget you'll need to [register your app as an oauth-client](http://twitter.com/oauth_clients) with Twitter to get your API key and secret, which authenticates your app with Twitter OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [this free open source Twitter client made for iPhone](http://github.com/takuma104/ntlniph).. it implements OAuth authentication and API calls for accessing all timelines:

Its a git repository. To download it to your mac, install a git client, and then open up a terminal and type:

```
git clone http://github.com/takuma104/ntlniph
```

Next open up this project, go to Project > Edit Project Settings. Select the Build tab, and select the iPhone SDK you are using from your list. Select Build > Run and you should be good to go.

I've studied this code very extensively for a similar client I had to build. Let me know if you have any questions on which files to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) by Matt Gemmel. [Here's](http://www.2bros1blog.com/2010/07/switching-from-basic-to-xauth-with-mgtwitterengine-on-iphone/) a version and a tutorial with built in OAuthConsumer Library!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's explained in Twitter api docs and there's a link in [faq - see link in http://dev.twitter.com/pages/api_faq#attribution](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/api_faq#attribution)